# Live Template for Fluent-API Builder in IntelliJ

Tags: design-patterns, intellij-idea, code-generation, builder-pattern

If I wanted to generate a "fluent builder" in IntelliJ anyone know where to edit the live template that is used in the [Replace Constructor with Builder](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/replace-constructor-with-builder.html) feature?

The above mentioned feature will automatically build a Builder pattern object though with the common setAttribute naming convention instead of a more fluentlike naming pattern of .attribute or .withAttribute that I am looking for.

Ultimately I would like to just be able to change a setting / template that would be used in rendering the code similar as to how you can change the format of various other auto generated code within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

install plugn in 'Generate Fluent interface'

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6141?pr=idea