# How can I configure a live template that generates a builder method in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I oftentimes need to create builder methods in my code. These methods are similar to getters, but they `return this` and they use `with` instead of `get`.

To be faster with that task I'd like to create a live-template in IDEA.

This how far I got:

[image: configuration of the builder]

(in `~/.IntelliJIdea14/config/templates/user.xml` this looks like this:)

```xml
<template name="builderMethod" value="public $CLASS_NAME$ with$VAR_GET$(final $TYPE$ $PARAM_NAME$) {&#10;    this.$VAR$ = $PARAM_NAME$;&#10;    return this;&#10;}" description="create a builder method" toReformat="true" toShortenFQNames="true">
    <variable name="CLASS_NAME" expression="className()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="VAR" expression="complete()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="PARAM_NAME" expression="VAR" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="TYPE" expression="typeOfVariable(&quot;this.&quot; + VAR)" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <variable name="VAR_GET" expression="capitalize(VAR)" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="true" />
    <context>
      <option name="JAVA_EXPRESSION" value="false" />
      <option name="JAVA_DECLARATION" value="true" />
    </context>
  </template>
```

This nearly works, except for `typeOfVariable("this." + VAR)` which does not. I just guessed how to call this method, because I could not find any documentation on the syntax used in the expressions except for [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/live-template-variables.html#predefined_functions) which does not even mention a script language name or something that would make googling for easier.

**How do I fix the call to `typeOfVariable`?**

Bonus question: How can I get `complete()` for `VAR` to only show fields?

Similar question but not does not even have a start: [Live Template for Fluent-API Builder in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347294/live-template-for-fluent-api-builder-in-intellij)

Comment: Regarding the bonus question: I don't think it's possible to list only fields.

Comment: It's probably more convenient if you check the "Skip if defined" option for `TYPE` and `CLASS_NAME` variables since you probably never need to change the values generated for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `typeOfVariable("this." + VAR)` with `typeOfVariable(VAR)`.

**Edit:**

Another way to generate builder methods is to use an appropriate setter template (instead of live template).
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/generate-setter-dialog.html

There is already a built-in setter template named "Builder" which generates setters such as:

```
public Foo setBar(int bar) {
  this.bar = bar;
  return this;
}
```

You can create your own template (e.g by copying it) and change it so that the method prefix is `with`.
And to make the generated method parameter final go to settings:

- `Editor | Code Style | Java`
- Select the Code Generation tab
- Tick Make generated parameters final

[IntelliJ IDEA add final to auto-generated setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034470/intellij-idea-add-final-to-auto-generated-setters)

Comment: Weird. I could have sworn that I tested that. Obviously I did not, because it works.